# Recode a subset of column and row

Tags: r

I have a data.frame and i want to recode some specific column after selecting for some row value.
My data.frame look like this. First Column ID, second and third columns are value i would like to use to select specific rows, column 4 and above are the value store that i want to recode.

I have store the column name I want to recode in a vector -> list1

```
df <- data.frame(letters[1:10],letters[1:2],letters[3:4],rep(0:1,each=5),rep(1:0,each=5),rep(1:0,each=5),rep(1:0,each=5))

names(df)<-c("Sample","cond1","cond2","ge1","ge2","ge3","ge4")
df

list1  <-  c("ge1","ge3")
```

What i want to get:
when I select for cond1 == a and cond2 == c I can recode the value of specific column (listed in a vector) in this case column ge1 and ge3.

a.e if conditions are meet then ge1 and ge3 are recode as NA.

I have tried things like : 
`df$cond1[df$cond1 == "a" & df$cond2 =="c"]`
and many other but I always fail!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're wanting to set conditional rows of specific columns to `NA` ?

```
df[df$cond1=="a" & df$cond2=="c", list1]  <- NA
```

Comment: Sorry, I didnn´t realized that! in my real dataset I always get this error: subset_mydata_cast[subset_mydata_cast$Bait.Set=="HemoSeq1.0", baitset.FL.Ontogeny]  <- NA
Error in `*tmp*`[[j]] : recursive indexing failed at level 2

Comment: Check that baitset.FL.Ontogeny is a character vector and that subset_mydata_cast is a data.frame - that error message seems to be associated with subsetting incorrect data structures

Comment: str(unique.FL.Ontogeny.baitset) chr [1:30] "BIRC3" "BRWD3" "CCND2" and str(df) 'data.frame': 304 obs. of  130 variables:
 $ Sample.Name: Factor w/ 314 levels "1075","1104",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ Individual : Factor w/ 314 levels "1075","1104",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 10 11 12 13 ...
 $ Project    : Factor w/ 2 levels "FL_discovery_GLSG",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Bait.Set   : Factor w/ 2 levels "HemoSeq1.0","PLG_FL1.0": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...

Comment: str(unique.FL.Ontogeny.baitset) is not necessarily str(baitset.FL.Ontogeny) ?

Comment: str(FL.Ontogeny.baitset) chr [1:30] "BIRC3" "BRWD3" "CCND2"

Comment: OK, to try and diagnose the problem, can you report what you get if you type `lapply(baitset.FL.Ontogeny, function(x) {class(subset_mydata_cast[[x]])})` and `table(subset_mydata_cast$Bait.Set=="HemoSeq1.0")`

Comment: Thanks! I Find out that one colname was wrong! now is working also in the real data frame!